# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. SQL Server

Tags: sql

We got some records in a table `Employee`. And different `Students` are linked with a particular `ClassId`. In the screenshot, `StudentId` 5,6 belongs to `ClassId` 1, while `StudentId` 5,6,7 belongs to another `ClassId` 2.

[image]

I want to fetch the `ClassId` from above table that only contains `StudentId` 5 and 6. So in above example it should return `ClassId` 1. The tricky part is that the value 5 and 6 is coming from another table.

So when I run below query it throws an error

```
SELECT ClassId
FROM employee
GROUP BY ClassId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN StudentId NOT IN (select id from test) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

If I remove the sub query part then it works fine

```
SELECT ClassId
FROM employee
GROUP BY ClassId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN StudentId NOT IN (5,6) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Below are the create table scripts for both of above tables

```
CREATE TABLE Student (Id INT) 
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (5),(6)

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
     Id INT IDENTITY, 
     ClassId INT, 
     StudentId INT
)

INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7)
```

Can someone suggest a workaround to run the first query without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having` like this:

```
SELECT e.ClassId
FROM employee e LEFT JOIN
     test t
     ON t.StudentId = e.id
GROUP BY e.ClassId
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(t.StudentId) AND      -- all rows in `e` match a row in `t`
       COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test) -- all match
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution on this. Both answers are working so we have 2 different ways to resolve this. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not allowed, but you can do `left join`. then use `coalesce()` to check those which are not in `test` table.

```
select t1.ClassId 
from employee t1
left join test t2 on t2.id = t1.StudentId
group by t1.ClassId
having count(case when coalesce(t2.id, 0) = 0 then 1 end)= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply to simplify the `HAVING` clause.

```
declare @Student table (ID int) ; 
insert into @Student values (5),(6) ;
declare @employee table (ID int identity, ClassId int, StudentId int)  ; 
insert into @employee values (1,5),(1,6), (2,5),(2,6), (2,7) ; 


SELECT e.ClassId  AS ClassId , COUNT(e.StudentId)  
FROM @employee AS e 
CROSS APPLY ( 
    SELECT ID
    FROM @Student AS s
    WHERE s.ID = e.StudentId 
) AS student 
GROUP BY e.ClassId 
HAVING COUNT(e.StudentId) = (SELECT COUNT('8') FROM @Student) ;
```